# how to create docker image in jenkins piepline?

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to docker, I want to load a docker image that is located on a repository, I want this done inside a jenkins pipeline, so what are the steps that I should go through? if there's a good reference or guide for this please share it.

Comment: Your title says “create”, text says “load”, please clarify what exactly you want to do. Jenkins documents explain the Docker methods quite well.

Comment: I'm new to docker so I'm a bit confused of what are the steps to have a docker image and what are the correct terms to use , and still isnt clear for me the steps or the full process to have a docker image, whether I am creating or loading it.
In my question I want to load a docker image, however still not clear to me how to create a docker image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use agent for using a docker image specifically for a stage.

```
stage("Any Stage") {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'YOUR_IMAGE'
            reuseNode true                  
            }
        }
        steps {
            script {
                //TODO
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay so now that I understand docker better, I guess I asked my question wrongly, so the point is I want to load an image form a repository and run it inside a jenkins pipeline (that in first stage), and in the later stage I want the jenkins machine to be able to communicate with the docker.